# Find string within a string and save it to file on BioPython

Tags: python, string

I want to crop this `gi|1168222|sp|P46098.1|5HT3A_HUMAN` to get this `P46098` but for any sequence of this kind `gi|"RANDOM"|sp|"SEQUENCE"|"RANDOM"`. 
Here is an example:

```
gi|1168222|sp|P46098.1|5HT3A_HUMAN
gi|1168223|sp|P35563.2|5HT3A_RAT
gi|112809|sp|P23979.1|5HT3A_MOUSE
gi|24211440|sp|O70212.1|5HT3A_CAVPO
gi|113067|sp|P22770|ACHA7_CHICK
```

I just want that between `sp|` and `.` or `|` if there is no `.` This is what i got until now:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import re

handle = open("seqdumpsp.txt", "rU")
for record in SeqIO.parse(handle, "fasta") :
    line = record.id
    i1 = line.index('sp|')
    i2 = line.index('.')
    line = line.replace(line[:i1], '', line)
    line = line.replace(x[i2:], '')
    print line
handle.close()
```

However this doesn't work because I cannot use i1 and i2 in replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By String processing:**

1. Iterate every line form the content by `for` loop.
2. Find "sp|" world in line. and set start index to it.
3. Find "." character and "|" character and compare index of both.
4. Get end index from the step 3.
5. Add value into result.

**Demo**:

```
content = """gi|1168222|sp|P46098.1|5HT3A_HUMAN
gi|1168223|sp|P35563.2|5HT3A_RAT
gi|112809|sp|P23979.1|5HT3A_MOUSE
gi|24211440|sp|O70212.1|5HT3A_CAVPO
gi|113067|sp|P22770|ACHA7_CHICK"""

result = []

for line in content.split("\n"):
    start_index = line.find("sp|")
    if start_index==-1:
        continue

    #- +3 because lenght of sp| is 3
    end_index1 = line.find(".", start_index+3)
    end_index2 = line.find("|", start_index+3)

    if end_index1==-1 and end_index2==-1:
        continue
    elif end_index2==-1:
        end_index = end_index1
    elif end_index1==-1:
        end_index = end_index2
    elif end_index1 < end_index2:
        end_index = end_index1
    else:
        end_index = end_index2

    result.append(line[start_index+3:end_index])

print result
```

Output:

```
['P46098', 'P35563', 'P23979', 'O70212', 'P22770']
```

---

By **CSV**

1. As input is well structure, so use CSV module.
2. Read Input file by CSV module.
3. Use list comprehension  and split method to to get final result.

Demo:

```
import csv

input_file = "dp-input1.csv"

with open(input_file) as fp:
    root = csv.reader(fp, delimiter='|')
    result = [row[3].split(".")[0] for row in root]
    #for row in root:
    #    tmp = row[3].split(".")[0]
    #    result.append(tmp)

print "Final result:-", result
```

Output:

```
Final result:- ['P46098', 'P35563', 'P23979', 'O70212', 'P22770']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> line = 'gi|1168222|sp|P46098.1|5HT3A_HUMAN'

>>> line.split('|')
['gi', '1168222', 'sp', 'P46098.1', '5HT3A_HUMAN']

>>> line.split('|')[3]
'P46098.1'

>>> line.split('|')[3].split('.')
['P46098', '1']

>>> line.split('|')[3].split('.')[0]
'P46098'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just say `line.split('|')[3]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `re.search`:

```
lines  = """gi|1168222|sp|P46098.1|5HT3A_HUMAN
gi|1168223|sp|P35563.2|5HT3A_RAT
gi|112809|sp|P23979.1|5HT3A_MOUSE
gi|24211440|sp|O70212.1|5HT3A_CAVPO
gi|113067|sp|P22770|ACHA7_CHICK
"""
import re
r =  re.compile("(?<=\|sp\|)\w+")

for s in lines.splitlines():
      print(r.search(s).group(0))

P46098
P35563
P23979
O70212
P22770
```